# Convert a decimal number into one with decimalplaces after last digits

Tags: bash, awk

I currently have a bash script which gives me numbers such as *26084729776630091742*. This number is converted *26,084729776630091742* with the last 18 digits being decimal places, but how can I convert this in bash?

(The number I want to convert is an ethereum unit called WEI and the 18 last numbers are the decimal places. So it doesnt work adding a dot after the first 2 digits.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT2:***

```
echo "128084729776630091742" | awk '{gsub(/,/,"");print substr($0,1,length($0)-18) "," substr($0,length($0)-17)}'
```

---

***EDIT:*** As OP changed the sample so adding this code now.

```
echo "128,6436xxxx"  | awk '{gsub(/,/,"");print substr($0,1,2) "," substr($0,3)}'
```

---

If you are looking for only this specific example then following may help you.

```
echo "26084729776630091742" | awk '{print substr($0,1,2) "," substr($0,3)}'
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `sed`.

```
echo "26084729776630091742" | sed 's/\(..\)\(.*\)/\1,\2/'
```

Comment: unfortunately thats not working, as e.g. when i have 128,6436xxxx it would show up as 12,86436. (This number is an ethereum unit called WEI and the 18 last numbers are the decimal places)

Comment: @Preisschild, please check EDIT solution now and let me know?

Comment: Please check the updated question, I want to convert that number (e.g. 26084729776630091742) in 26,084729776630091742. But want to convert it by adding a dot (or comma) in front of the last 18 digits, so that e.g. 128084729776630091742 (that would be 128,084729776630091742) doesnt get converted to 12,8084729776630091742

Comment: @Preisschild, please check my EDIT2 and let me know if that helps you?>'

Answer (score 3):

what you are looking for is something like: `"${str:0:2},${str:2}"`

**Example in your case:**

```
str="26084729776630091742"
echo "${str:0:2},${str:2}"
```

prints `26,084729776630091742`

---

**EDIT as question was precised**

```
str="26084729776630091742133"
echo "${str:0:${#str}-18},${str:${#str}-18}"
```

prints `26084,729776630091742133`  with 18 decimal places  (works fine if `${#str}` > 18)

Comment: unfortunately thats not working, as e.g. when i have 128,6436xxxx it would show up as 12,86436

Comment: @Preisschild, but your example was NOT like that, please make sure you mention your requirements correctly in your posts, kindly do update your post with complete details now and let us know on same too.

Comment: @RavinSingh13 Sorry, thought it was enough by simply telling that only a dot should be added in front of the 18 last digits.

Comment: This is easily adapted, though: `${str:0:-18},${str:${#str}-18}`.

Comment: @chepner I think you meant `${str:0:${#str}-18},${...}` ?

Comment: Support for negative lengths was added in `bash` 4.2, which was released over 7 years ago.